# Extract all string constants from an angular.js project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is their a nifty way to extract all string constants from an angular.js project?

When I search a string, Intellij shows the results separately for string constants but one can't search an empty string.

Comment: What do you mean by "extract all string constants"?  Are you asking how to find all the variable assignments in your IDE?

Comment: Is requirement to return all characters within a string that are not vowels ?

Comment: Regexps are powerful enough to search for string literals, what about just using grep?

Comment: I just did it using regexes but my understanding is that IDE has a much more reliable handle on it and there must be a way to get all those string constants.